# Tzitzis showing in the presence of a dead woman?

Tags: women, death, tzitzis

One should not have tzitzis showing in the presence of a dead body. As [Chabad.org says:](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/536852/jewish/Miscellaneous-Tzitzit-Laws-and-Customs.htm)

> It is forbidden to be in the presence of a dead Jewish body while
>   one's tzitzit strings are out in the open. Doing so would constitute,
>   so to say, a subtle mockery of the deceased who can no longer perform
>   this mitzvah. One should therefore tuck his tzitzit into his pants
>   when:
>
> a) Within a Jewish cemetery.
>
> b) In the same house as a body (even if the corpse is in another
>   room).
>
> c) Within four cubits (approximately six feet) from a corpse or
>   grave—unless it is outdoors and there is a wall or fence which
>   separates them.

Is the rule the same in the presence of a dead woman, who is [not obligated in the mitzvah of tzitzit?](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/530119/jewish/The-Obligation.htm) (see footnote 1 in the link.)

Comment: A woman too can no longer perform the commandment, though she was never obligated.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92

Comment: Do sources that state that this does not even apply to dead males count as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote that you give implies that showing that you are getting "credit" for a mitzvah is an insult to the dead person who can no longer do mitzvos. This can be considered that the mais cannot do **any** mitzvos whether the person was chayav in it while alive or not. A woman is not chayav to wear tzitzis but is not forbidden to do so. Thus, it would still be "a subtle mockery of the deceased who can no longer perform" any mitzvos at all. This is a matter of logic based on the Tur and the Shulchan Aruch shown below.

Note that the Tur and the Shulchan Aruch are speaking of someone in a cemetery. However, the fact that they do not differentiate between men and women or mention the case of a dead woman at the funeral home seems to imply that this applies even to women.

[Tur Halacha 23 Seif 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x60) explicitly says that because we do not normally wear tzitzis on regular garments (but just for the mitzva) would be asur to wear tzitzis in any case because to the insult to the dead people. He does not mention wearing the tzitzis covered at all.

[Shulchan Aruch Halacha 23 Seif 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x374) says that it is asur and does not differentiate between a man and a woman.

> ... these words apply only if they are "open", but if they are covered, it is mutar.

This is repeated in the Biur Hagra and the B'eir Hataiv in order to state that it also applies to tefillin.

However, as @DoubleAA points out, while this appears to be the case (from logic) we actually see from

[משנה ברורה על אורח חיים כג](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.92)

> אבל בקבר אשה דבחייה ג"כ פטורה ליכא משום לועג לרש
>
> But at the grave of a woman who was patur even while she was alive, it
>   is not considered demeaning.

Comment: You're missing half the fun http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x617

Comment: @DoubleAA what do you want on that page?

Comment: @mevaqesh The only line that remotely deals with the question... There's only two Seifim even discussing Siman 23 which is the relevant Siman

Comment: I would like to upvote and accept the part of the answer which is the quote from the Mishnah Berurah. Do you, sabbahillel, have a source for your first assertion?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I added the citations from the Tur and the Shulchan Aruch with my reasoning for the first part of the posting.

Comment: Dittos to Double. How can you pass up the opportunity to discuss transgendered transmigration of souls?!