# How does tucking in one's Tzitzis help in a cemetery?

Tags: mitzvah, tzitzis, cemetery-grave

Based on [Not allowing one's tzitzis to show in a cemetary according to the Rambam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61660/not-allowing-ones-tzitzis-to-show-in-a-cemetary-according-to-the-rambam) and [Are all mitzvos forbidden near a grave? If not, why not? If yes, why not say so?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104294/are-all-mitzvos-forbidden-near-a-grave-if-not-why-not-if-yes-why-not-say-so), we find that wearing Tzitzis in a cemetery mocks the dead who can't perform Mitzvos anymore (even by women [Tzitzis showing in the presence of a dead woman?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71800/tzitzis-showing-in-the-presence-of-a-dead-woman)). However, even by tucking in the Tzitzis, it would seem that one is still performing a Mitzvah, albeit privately.

If the dead can still see the Mitzvah being performed, then how does tucking it in help? And if they can't see it being performed, then why tuck the Tzitzis in?

In other words, the dead should be able to see the Mitzvah being done anyways (think of X-Ray vision within their 4 Amos), in which case tucking in Tzitzis shouldn't help. And if they can't see it tucked in, then they shouldn't see it either way (they're covered in earth).

Or do we say that due to Kavod HaBriyos, we don't make the person take their Tzitzis off in public (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37793/17591)?

Comment: The language of the verse brought by Chazal is לועג לרש, scoffing at the poor. It would seem that if you hide them, you are not scoffing.

Comment: You're assuming the dead have x-ray vision. Why?

Comment: This Halachas is not about the corpses feeling, but about you.

It's insensitive to be showing off that you can still do Mitzvos. It's bad for your character development.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the Halacha, a tallis gadol that is only worn during davening should be removed according to some, while a Tallis Kattan just needs to have the strings tucked in. I understood that the tallis kattan is not any worse than a shirt, the tzitzis are there because once your wearing a 4 cornered beged you need tzitzis, therefore by hiding them, your showing that it’s merely your shirt. Just like you don’t remove your kippa. Removing them entirely is not an option because then you’d have to remove a piece of your clothing.

Comment: The dead obviously know you are wearing tzitzis still because it is a mitzvah for the living to wear tzitzis. The point of tucking them in is simply to "hide" them, so that they are not visible, in order not to **scoff** before them לועג לרש

Comment: @DannySchoemann, just to add to this comment. This is similar to the idea quoted in the name of baalei mussar (not sure of source) as to why we cover the challah during kiddush. Of course the bread does not have feelings, rather it is to heighten our own sensitivity.  I believe that is the message here as well.